# How to convert blank or empty string or whitespace to null in ADF mapping dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-adf

Suppose I have column1 which is having only empty string, now I want to convert it to null.

Answer (score 1):

```
iif(column1=='',toString(null()),column1)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
iif(toString(length(rtrim(Column))) != "0", Column,toString(null()))
```

Here is the answer to this. I have it working in my ADF. Some columns records are sent in a flat file with empty spaces. This code will trim white spaces, then count the characters and IF 0, then change to NULL. I spent a few days on this working several different approaches and this is the only one that works. SSIS has an option 'Retain NULLs'; ADF should add that feature to Source Files.